# How can I add 0s to a string based on string length difference compared to target length?

Tags: excel, vba, string, loops

I need to make sure all cells in each column have that column's target length.
When the target length is larger than the actual length of the string value in the given cell, x amount of 0s must be added in front in order to make the string's length be equal to the target.

```vb
Dim row_counter1 As Long
Dim char1 As Integer
Dim char_dif1 As Integer
Dim char_targ1 As Integer
char_targ1 = 2
For row_counter1 = 2 To last_row_index(output, 1)
    char1 = Len(output.Cells(row_counter1, 1))
    char_dif1 = char_targ1 - char1
    Debug.Print char_dif1
Next row_counter1
```

`last_row_index` is a UDF using the `End.xlUp` method to find last continuous row index.
The loop works, giving me the difference in Integer format.

How do I turn that integer into 0s that go in front of `cell.value`?

Comment: You talk about integers, but why don't you just format the whole column with padding zeros based on target length?

Comment: And do you know what "that column's target length" is? Do you really mean two characters? Do the cells to be evaluated have numeric values (besides the leading zeros)? Do you need such evaluated **strings**?

Comment: @FaneDuru the target length is the char_targ1 value. In this case it is 2, but it goes up to 8 in other columns. The cells to be evaluated have a mix of numbers and letters, so I formatted them as Text in the sheet.
An example would be something like "MA02Y891" or "M02".

Comment: Your 'example' is not too eloquent if you do not supply more details... In the case you show us, what is to be done? Which is that target length? Should "M02" become "00000M02"? or "M0000002? Of course, supposing that the target should be 8, as the first string... Otherwise, the `clarification` looks even more confuse. And **do you want the processed result as a String**?

Comment: @JvdV thank you for the suggestion, I did not even know padding was a thing. What I am going to go with is:

formatted_string = Format$(cell_value1, "00")
output.Cells(row_counter1, 1).Value = formatted_string

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FaneDuru if you read carefully, you will notice that most of your questions have already been answered in the post. If the target length in the example is 2, I substract the length of the current string and that gives me the number of 0s I need. 

If target is 8, and I have M02, I would need 00000M02, as the 0s need to go in front.

Lastly, since these have both letters and numbers and they are qualitative in nature, the output should also be string.

Comment: @deepwave43, understood but with a combination of letters `Format()` is not going to work. If you had integers only there is the option to format the entire column in a single go instead of a tedious loop per cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function addZero(rng As Range, strLength As Long) As Variant
    rng.NumberFormat = "@"
    addZero = Evaluate("RIGHT(""" & String(strLength, "0") & """&" & rng.Address & "," & strLength & ")")
End Function
```

It can be called from your (adapted) code in the next way:

```
Sub PlaceZero()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastR As Long

 Dim char_targ1 As Long: char_targ1 = 5
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR)
 
 rng.value = addZero(rng, char_targ1)
End Sub
```

No iteration needed using `Evaluate`...

But if you will try setting `char_targ1` to a length lower than the existing string, it will be truncated to the `char_targ1` length, of course.

To previously check if the non zero characters in each cell are less than 'char_targ1`, the next way can be used (directly in the calling` Sub`):

```
 Dim arr, MTCH
 arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ",""0"",""""))<" & char_targ1 & ",""x"",""""))")
 MTCH = Application.match("x", arr, 0)
 If IsNumeric(MTCH) Then MsgBox "There are strings with less characters (except zero) than :" & char_targ1 & "...": Exit Sub
```

It should be placed before the code line:

```
 rng.value = addZero(rng, char_targ1)
```

But it counts also the existing zero characters inside the original string. I mean, not only the leading zero characters...

Answer (score 1):

in the cell like this,
e.g. for 10 digits of length:

```
=RIGHT(“0000000000000”&A1,10)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going with the format$(A1, "00"), but will check this one out too to see which one works better for me.

Comment: No worries. This solution has also a risk if the length of the original string is bigger than the setting (e.g. 10 char) it will cut off the leading characters of the original string accordingly

Comment: The VBA alternative is `Right(String(l, "0") & s, l)` where `l` is the target length and `s` the input.

Answer (score 0):

> **REPT**(*text*, *number_times*)

***Example***

```
application.WorksheetFunction.Rept(0,10)
```